# Closing one window sends others to the background

Tags: 11.10, window-manager, fullscreen, focus

After updating to 11.10, if I have a few non-fullscreen windows on top of a fullscreen window, if I close one of the non-fullscreen windows, the other non-fullscreen windows are pushed behind the fullscreen window in the focus stack.

Comment: This happens to me too, I'd be interested to know if there's a solution.  Perhaps it's a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've submitted a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/888704).